# New-Item Creating Extension-less File Instead of Directory

Tags: powershell

I am trying to automate log copying between multiple remote computers and a shared folder on said remote computer's network. The script is working fine for the most part, but occasionally (I cannot figure out why) an extension-less file is created instead of a file folder, and the logs' contents are copied into it. When I edit it with notepad++, I can see the contents of the log file I was trying to copy into the folder.

I have this script on multiple remote computers, which all transfer the logs to the same shared network folder (but to different sub-directories). On each machine, I have the script executing at the same time (3:00 AM) via a Windows Task.

```
$sharedFolderPath = "\\xXxXxXx\xXxXxX\xXxXx\"
$yesterdaysDate = (get-date).AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

#Create Daily Directories
if (-Not(Test-Path "$sharedFolderPath$yesterdaysDate")) {
    new-item -Path "$sharedFolderPath"                      -Name $yesterdaysDate   -ItemType directory
    new-item -Path "$sharedFolderPath\$yesterdaysDate"      -Name "BMS"             -ItemType directory
    new-item -Path "$sharedFolderPath\$yesterdaysDate"      -Name "BPS"             -ItemType directory
    new-item -Path "$sharedFolderPath\$yesterdaysDate"      -Name "DDS"             -ItemType directory
    new-item -Path "$sharedFolderPath\$yesterdaysDate"      -Name "POS"             -ItemType directory
    new-item -Path "$sharedFolderPath\$yesterdaysDate"      -Name "SCAPPS"          -ItemType directory
    new-item -Path "$sharedFolderPath\$yesterdaysDate"      -Name "TRCS"            -ItemType directory
    new-item -Path "$sharedFolderPath\$yesterdaysDate"      -Name "Optitrack"       -ItemType directory
    new-item -Path "$sharedFolderPath\$yesterDaysDate\DDS"  -Name "Layer Files"     -ItemType directory
    new-item -Path "$sharedFolderPath\$yesterDaysDate\TRCS" -Name "Catch-All"       -ItemType directory
}
```

Working correctly, I'd expect a folder called "2019-06-30" (or whatever yesterday's date is) to be made, with folders BMS, BPS, DDS, Optitrack, POS, SCAPPS, and TRCS inside, that have their respective logs stored in them.

After the code I provided, I've added these lines:

```
#fail-safes
new-item -Path "$sharedFolderPath\$yesterdaysDate"  -Name "DDS" -ItemType directory -Force
new-item -Path "$sharedFolderPath\$yesterdaysDate"  -Name "BMS" -ItemType directory -Force
```

Which has seemed to fix the problem. However, for the sake of being robust, I would like to know what's causing this so that I can fix it properly.

Comment: Have you validated the server share's path exists?  You can use the `-Force` switch to avoid creating the entire structure: `New-Item -Path "$sharedFolderPath\$yesterdaysDate\DDS\Layer Files" -Type Directory -Force`

Comment: So I should be using -Force on all of these?

Comment: My point is you don't need all of them.

Comment: I think I may have forgotten to include a piece of information: a new folder is created each day which should have the subdirectory structure in my code (so the folders shouldn't exist before the script is run). The name of the folder should be yesterday's date.